# Stripe API error - "Received unknown parameter: source"

Tags: api, stripe-payments, in-app-subscription

Creating subscription site in wix code. I keep getting a 400 unknown parameter: source error. (/subscripton)

if you can spot where i am going wrong it would be appreciated. thanks!

```
import { fetch } from 'wix-fetch';

export async function subscription(token, item) {

    const cart = item;

    const apiKey = "PRIVATEAPI";

    const response = await
    fetch("https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions", {

        method: 'post',

        headers: {

            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",

            "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey

        },

        body: encodeBody(token, cart)
    });
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {

        const ret = await response.json();

        return { "chargeId": ret.id };

    }

    let res = await response.json(); 

    let err = res.error.message;

    let code = res.error.code;

    let type = res.error.type;

    return { "error": err, "code": code, "type": type };

}

 function encodeBody(token, cart) {

    let encoded = "";

    for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(cart)) {

        encoded = encoded.concat(k, "=", encodeURI(v), "&");
    }
     encoded = encoded.concat("source=", encodeURI(token));
     return encoded;
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to say that help is wanted, especially by SHOUTING IT. If you didn't need help, you wouldn't be posting here.

Comment: Hi @TheDylanVoyages, creating a Subscription requires a Customer: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create, 

It looks like right now you are only passing in a token. You should first create a Customer with that card as their source, then use that Customer.id to create the subscription

Comment: There seems to be some good reference documentation here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=node

Notice that stipe provides their own node.js library, perhaps using it would be easier.

Comment: @TheDylanVoyages also, it looks like you are creating a subscription client-side from your page? Subscriptions should be created from your backend, preferably using Stripe's API libraries

Answer (score 1):

welcome to StackOverflow!

It looks like you're creating a Subscription. According to the API docs: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=ruby

`customer` is a required parameter when creating subscriptions on Stripe. You would need to create a Customer first, attaching a tokenized card to the Customer as a source. Then, you can create a subscription, by passing `customer: customer.id`

Also, is this request being made client-side? Requests made with your secret API key should be made from your server-side code and preferably using Stripe's API libraries: https://stripe.com/docs/libraries

Since you're using Subscriptions, you should also look into the new version of Stripe Checkout (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout), it allows creating subscriptions with client-side code with just a few lines of code!

Answer (score -1):

You're likely passing additional keys that you're not expecting to when you call `encodeBody(token, cart)`.

You should verify that the keys you're passing in `token` and `cart` are all valid according to the documentation at https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create.